# Aws arn kinesis access to multiple streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis

I would like to grant access to a specific user to multiple kinesis streams that start with a prefix in aws.
Is there a way to write something like this?

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"kinesis: *"
],
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:kinesis:<region>:<account_id>:stream/prefix-*"
]
```

So that the user has access to all the streams that start with  ***prefix-***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the wildcard in the resource name does work.
The problem was that:

```
"Action": [
    "kinesis: *"
]
```

was suppose to be:

```
"Action": [
"kinesis:*"
]
```

and that extra white space before the action was invalidating the policy.